# Linearlayout messed up with the horizontal alignment

Tags: xml, android-layout

i have this layout using LinearLayout (vertical orientation) as the parent and inside it i add another LinearLayout (horizontal orientation for the custom navbar / navigation drawer / custom made toolbar).

everything seem to be looking good on design page but when the app run the numberBtn are place lower than other Button. plus it seem that android:layout_weight do not have any effect at all. i tried to change the apptitle weight to 0.2 but it stay to have the same width. what is going on? why it did not do anything?

here is the screenshot as you can see the button near account button are not align and in lower position than the rest of the button
[image]

so here is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/silver">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.08"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sideBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/numberBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/number"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/accountBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </ListView>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.04"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/micBtn2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mic"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
        </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one ......

> Tips For Futher Development.

For next time whenever you playing with `LinearLayout` make `weight` 1 to the one who want more space and let other to be `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Or You want to give MORE SPACE to 2 view then divide your `weight` accordingly and let other to be `WRAP_CONTENT` and SO ON.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/silver">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/sideBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/menu"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/app_name"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/textLarge"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:textAlignment="center" />
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/numberBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/number"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/accountBtn"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="0.1"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/profile"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainlist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        </ListView>

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/micBtn2"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mic"
                    android:background="@color/white" />
        </GridLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Output:- [image]

Comment: what did you change?? it still give the same result

Comment: i remove your `grid layout` `weight` and change height to   `wrap_content`.

Comment: what is your trying to achieve ?? will you upload screenshot ?

Comment: i add the screen shot, the number button is not align with the rest of the button

Comment: You are welcome and have a look on **EDIT Answer Tips** for further development.